# How to reset font configuration to default settings?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have been doing some customization to my ubuntu Box related to font settings. Now all the font settings for whole system have been badly scrambled. I am feeling it very hard to reset all the settings too default again.

I have been modifying system---> Preference ---> Appearance.

Please let me know, if there exists any way to reset my font configuration to default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found this answer on Ubuntu forums, which seems to be very helpful:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/4989/reset-gnome-font-configuration